About regular value theorem.
Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $C\in(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$. Consider
$$\Sigma=\{(x_1 , x_2 , y_1 , y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^{4} : y^{2}_{1}+y^{2}_{2}=C^{2}(x^{2}_{1}+x^{2}_{2})^{\lambda}\}.$$
Note that $(0,0,0,0)\in\Sigma$.
Consider the map $F:\mathbb{R}^{4}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $F(x_1 , x_2 , y_1 , y_2)=y^{2}_{1}+y^{2}_{2}-C^{2}(x^{2}_{1}+x^{2}_{2})^{\lambda}$ and $\Sigma=F^{-1}(0)$. Also
$$dF_{(x_1 , x_2 , y_1 , y_2)}=\begin{bmatrix}
-2x_{1}C^{2}\lambda(x^{2}_{1}+x^{2}_{2})^{\lambda-1} & -2x_{2}C^{2}\lambda(x^{2}_{1}+x^{2}_{2})^{\lambda-1} & 2y_1 & 2y_2\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $0$ is a critical value of $F$, since $dF_{(0,0,0,0)}=0$.
My question: Is $F^{-1}(0)\setminus\{(0,0,0,0)\}$ a smooth submanifold?

So does the derivative vanish at any other point of $F^{-1}(0)$?

Indeed, in my calculation, points in $F^{-1}(0)\setminus{(0,0,0,0)}$ has derivative with $DF\not=0$.

Therefore $F^{-1}(0)\setminus{(0,0,0,0)}$ is a smooth submanifold of codimension $1$, right?

Yes, right! ....

Thanks a lot for the help.
